# ngrx/effects switchMap no longer working in Angular2 RC5

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm  using ngrx/effects in my Angular2 application and since the release of RC5 I'm getting errors. This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Effect, Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { UserActions } from './user.actions';
import { LoginService } from '../login';

constructor(
  private updates$: Actions,
  private userActions: UserActions,
  private loginService: LoginService
) {}

@Effect() loadUser$ = this.updates$
  .ofType(UserActions.LOAD)
  .switchMap(() => this.loginService.loadUserData())
  .map(user => this.userActions.loadUserComplete(user.userData));
```

The code above worked fine in Angular2 RC4 with ngrx/effects 1.1.1.

But when I upgraded Angular to RC5 I got the error: `Unhandled Promise rejection: this.updates$.ofType(...).switchMap is not a function`

I then upgraded ngrx/effects to the latest version 2.0.0-beta.2 (which according to the documentation should be customized for the new RC5 NgModule) but got the exact same error as above. And yes, i changed the `whenAction()` functions to `ofType()` in this step.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't automatically have all RxJS operators imported in an angular 2 project. Did you try importing the `switchMap` operator manually?

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

This must exist somewhere in your code, probably it was imported by a third-party library before which doesn't import the operator any longer.

Comment: I have this import, but I get an error saying `Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type Observable<{ [key: string]: any; }>`

Answer (score 0):

using `import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators'`
worked for me! This is using version 6.4.0